# Issue Building R package with RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, package

I am building an R package with RcppArmadillo using RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton() in order to facilitate usage.

My code is structured as follows:

```
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(name = "HACSim", code_files = c("accumulate.cpp", "HAC.sim.R", "HAC.simrep.R"),example_code = FALSE).
```

It runs fine. However, I get a warning message:

```
Warning message:
In (function (name = "anRpackage", list = character(), environment = .GlobalEnv,  :
  Invalid file name(s) for R code in ./HACSim/R:
  'accumulate.cpp'
 are now renamed to 'z<name>.R'
```

I find it odd that R does not recognize the .cpp extension.

Is this not the correct way of specifying a C++ file using RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not the correct way. Looking at `?RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton` you are referred to `?package.skeleton` for the `code_files` argument. There it says:

> `code_files`
>   a character vector with the paths to R code files to build the package around. See ‘Details’.

There simply is no way of specifying C++ files with `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton`. I suggest to include only the `.R` files and manually copy the `.cpp` files to the `src` folder.

Comment: Thanks. I see now. This was expressly stated in the generated Readme file.